# How can I get text of a Textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make an application, for fun. but i can't see a way to reuse the information i will get from user, in the textbox. how can return that value and use it within my application?

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text = "1" ))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

When i try to run the application, it will change the text 1, even if i wrote something like 13251.

The !string.IsNullOrEmpty, was something visual studio(resharper) put on, so the if statement did not show a redline.

Comment: Post your code. Whatever you have tried.

Comment: You accepted the answer that not related to your question?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very simple, we say that the `TextBox` is named `textBox1`, you need to use the **Property `Text`**.
Example:

```
string example = textBox1.Text;
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks! it maked sense, but how can i put that in a if statement? cant seem to make it work

Comment: `if(textBox1.Text == "Your Text"){/* true*/}else{ /* false */}` or `if(textBox1.Text.Equals("Your Text"){/* true*/}else{ /* false */}`

Comment: Dude your are the best! cant thanks you enough.
i forgot to .text afterwards!

Comment: No problem. I help where i can.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have used

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text = "1"))
```

The compiler will execute

```
textBox1.Text = "1"
```

As part of the `if` statement. So change it to this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("You have chosen 1");
} 
else 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("You are wrong"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me some what. but how do i get that thing into a string? 

i have tried this:

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text = "1" ))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have chossen 1");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You wrong");
            }

But it replace what i have wrote in textbox to 1.

Comment: try this instead of your code: `(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) { MessageBox.Show("You have chossen 1"); } else { MessageBox.Show("You wrong"); }`. You don't need assign any value to `textBox1.Text` while checking it.

Comment: Well, then the dont do what i want it to. want to learn how to make a real if statement. 

Where you insert something in the text box, and if it is 1, it do somthing, if somthing else, it will do something else

just like a normal if statement.

Comment: See answer . I edited it

Comment: Arghh, that makes sense! thanks :) learning so much today